# Error de sintaxis al asignar texto a un widget Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Intento hacer una ventana con scroll y me da error de sintexis en el código:

> ```
> texto = tk.Label(elframe,wraplength=500,text="El ejemplo de texto
>                                                                  ^
> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
> ```

Este es el código:

```
import tkinter as tk
ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Scrolling")
scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(ventana)
c=tk.Canvas(ventana,background="orange",yscrollcommand=scrollba.set)
scrollbar.config(command=c.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
elframe=tk.Frame(c)
c.pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
c.create_window(0,0,window=elframe,anchor="nw")
texto = tk.Label(elframe,wraplength=500,text="El ejemplo de texto


expositivo que os voy a mostrar en este artículo tiene 
como finalidad el hecho de ser un punto de partida o
plantilla para la creación de vuestros propios textos 
expositivos. Siempre digo que las modalidades discursivas 
como la exposición se pueden aprender, pero también se deben enseñar.

Lo importante a la hora de enseñar un texto expositivo a los alumnos es 
crear una plantilla básica para que todos los textos que se elaboren tengan 
la misma forma y el mismo punto de partida.
¿Qué necesitamos para elaborar un ejemplo de texto expositivo básico?

Es importante recordar que el texto expositivo tiene un carácter informativo.
 Por tanto, predominará a lo largo del texto la objetividad. En un texto 
 expositivo
 no cabe ni la opinión personal, ni el uso de la primera persona. Además hay
 que evitar el uso de verbos en pasado porque corremos el riesgo de contar en 
 lugar de informar.

1. Título. El título será breve y preferentemente un Sintagma Nominal con un 
Complemento del Núcleo (opcional).

2. Párrafos. Cada párrafo irá separado por un espacio en blanco. Esto facilita
 su lectura y comprensión.

    Párrafo 1. Introducción. Se presenta de forma informativa el tema del que
    va a tratar la exposición.
    Parte 2. Desarrollo. Suele ser la parte más extensa de la exposición porque
    en ella se profundiza en el tema de lo que se está exponiendo.
    Parte 3. Conclusión. El texto expositivo finaliza incidiendo en algún
    aspecto aparecido en párrafos anteriores o se añade algún tipo de 
    información nueva.

3. Conectores textuales.

    Párrafo 1. Aparecerá un conector textual después de la primera oración.
    Párrafo 2. Aparecerá un conector textual al principio del párrafo.
    Párrafo 3. Aparecerá un conector textual a principio del párrafo.

4. Persona gramatical. Se utilizará la tercera persona del singular.

5. Tiempo verbal. Se utilizará el presente de indicativo.

6. Otros aspectos lingüísticos:

    Paréntesis
    Siglas
    Fotografías
    Gráficos y esquemas

Aquí tenéis un ejemplo de texto expositivo básico. La recopilación de datos se
 ha extraído de la wikipedia:
", background="turquoise")
texto.pack()
ventana.update()
c.config(scrollregion=c.bbox("all"))
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yo no entiendo esta pregunta. Que tiene que ver todo lo del medio con el problema?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta para que sea clara. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás intentando usar solo unas comillas dobles para definir un literal de cadena multilínea. Esto causa que al final de la primera línea de texto tenga lugar un error de sintaxis ya que espera las comillas de cierre. Estas dos opciones son inválidas:

```
"Hola
StackOverflow
en español"

'Hola
StackOverflow
en español'
```

Para poder usar cadenas con varias líneas tienes que utilizar tres comillas dobles o simples.

```
"""Hola
StackOverflow
en español"""

'''Hola
StackOverflow
en español'''
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Scrolling")
scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(ventana)
c = tk.Canvas(ventana,background="orange",yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command = c.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
elframe=tk.Frame(c)
c.pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)
c.create_window(0, 0, window=elframe, anchor="nw")
texto = tk.Label(elframe, wraplength=500, justify="left", background="turquoise", text=
"""El ejemplo de texto expositivo que os voy a mostrar en este artículo tiene 
como finalidad el hecho de ser un punto de partida o
plantilla para la creación de vuestros propios textos 
expositivos. Siempre digo que las modalidades discursivas como la exposición
se pueden aprender, pero también se deben enseñar.

Lo importante a la hora de enseñar un texto expositivo a los alumnos es 
crear una plantilla básica para que todos los textos que se elaboren tengan 
la misma forma y el mismo punto de partida.
¿Qué necesitamos para elaborar un ejemplo de texto expositivo básico?

Es importante recordar que el texto expositivo tiene un carácter informativo.
Por tanto, predominará a lo largo del texto la objetividad. En un texto
expositivo no cabe ni la opinión personal, ni el uso de la primera persona.      
Además hay que evitar el uso de verbos en pasado porque corremos
el riesgo de contar en lugar de informar.

1. Título. El título será breve y preferentemente un Sintagma Nominal con un 
Complemento del Núcleo (opcional).

2. Párrafos. Cada párrafo irá separado por un espacio en blanco. Esto facilita
 su lectura y comprensión.

    Párrafo 1. Introducción. Se presenta de forma informativa el tema del que
    va a tratar la exposición.
    Parte 2. Desarrollo. Suele ser la parte más extensa de la exposición porque
    en ella se profundiza en el tema de lo que se está exponiendo.
    Parte 3. Conclusión. El texto expositivo finaliza incidiendo en algún
    aspecto aparecido en párrafos anteriores o se añade algún tipo de 
    información nueva.

3. Conectores textuales.

    Párrafo 1. Aparecerá un conector textual después de la primera oración.
    Párrafo 2. Aparecerá un conector textual al principio del párrafo.
    Párrafo 3. Aparecerá un conector textual a principio del párrafo.

4. Persona gramatical. Se utilizará la tercera persona del singular.

5. Tiempo verbal. Se utilizará el presente de indicativo.

6. Otros aspectos lingüísticos:

    Paréntesis
    Siglas
    Fotografías
    Gráficos y esquemas

Aquí tenéis un ejemplo de texto expositivo básico. La recopilación de datos se
ha extraído de la wikipedia:""")

texto.pack()
ventana.update()
c.config(scrollregion=c.bbox("all"))
ventana.mainloop()
```

No obstante esto "ensucia" bastante el código, te recomendaría que colocaras el texto en un archivo y en la aplicación simplemente los leas:

```
import tkinter as tk


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Scrolling")
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(ventana)
c = tk.Canvas(ventana, background="orange", yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=c.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
elframe=tk.Frame(c)
c.pack(side="left",fill="both", expand=True)
c.create_window(0, 0, window=elframe, anchor="nw")

with open("texto.txt") as f:
    contenido = f.read()

texto = tk.Label(elframe, wraplength=500, justify="left",
                 background="turquoise", text=contenido)    
texto.pack()
ventana.update()
c.config(scrollregion=c.bbox("all"))
ventana.mainloop()
```